# How to get Max time took by each customer by each day

Tags: sql

I want to calculate Max time took by ID on each day

```
ID                  date    Time 
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/30/2018   16558
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/30/2018   22570
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   6673
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   2709
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   19968
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   2002
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   6754
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   6954
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   16739
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   8431
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/16/2018   16978
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/2/2018    21776
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/2/2018    14015
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/2/2018    294097
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/2/2018    543202
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/12/2018   18563
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/12/2018   17547
```

Result should be

```
ID                  date    Time 
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/30/2018   16558
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/14/2018   19968
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/16/2018   16978
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/2/2018    543202
220B8DAAA53F35B 9/12/2018   18563
```

Please help me to write query

Thanks

Comment: What **RDBMS** is this for? And what have **YOU** tried so far?? Please show us

Comment: You need to tell us which version of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).  And also, please include the work you have already done and show us a query.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is the one way to do this :

```
select id, date, max(time)
from table t
group by id, date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the query selects the maximum time value for each grouping of ID and Date values

```
SELECT Max([Time])
       ,[Date]
       ,[ID]
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY [ID],[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Classic rownumber

```
select top 1 with ties ID,date,time
from [your table]
order by row_number() over (partition by id,date order by time desc)
```

I am going to leave this answer up here for you to review, but the other options meet your needs for efficiently.

However, this is a very good method for getting the whole row back for the record you are chasing down. Often times, you will need to exclude columns in order to get the aggregation that you need.

Comment: While this would probably work, wouldn't organizing a partition be a little overkill and have some pretty low performance?

Comment: i guess i was getting an answer to a more complicated question that is usually asked.